# Converting javascript code to PHP : Determining what return (1) means in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, return

I have this code in JS

```
function calc(bth){
    var y,cont;
    y=(Math.abs(1965-bth))/4;
    y=y-Math.floor(y);    
    if(y){
      cont=calc(bth+1);
      return(cont+1);
    } else {
      return(1); // <-- what is the meaning of this line?
    }
 }
```

I converted it to PHP as

```
function calc($yr)
{       
    $y = (abs(1965 - $yr))/4;
    $y = $y- floor($y);    
    if($y)
    {
       $cont= calc($yr+1);       
       return ($cont + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        return (1); //<--- stuck here
    }
}
```

### The Problem

I realized that `return (1)` in javascript is not the same as `return (1)` in PHP. I went over some SO topics regarding this topic but didn't find a suitable match for my kind of scenario.

In my context, what would `return (1)` return in javascript? I would also appreciate if the values of `return (0)` and `return (-1)` in javascript are made known to me so that I get acquainted with this information.

Comment: `return (1);` means *"return the number 1"*. It's the same as `return 1;` and does not have any special meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Don't overcomplicate the problem. It will simply return `1`, as if you write `return 1`.

Most probably brackets were left from copying of `return(cont+1)`.

Comment: Are you sure? Because I seem to be getting different values for the same argument in javascript and PHP

Comment: @asprin Yes I am sure. Parentheses make no difference for `return` statement in both languages.

Answer (score 1):

`return` is not a function, `()` is not necessary for return statement.

Just do with `return cont + 1;` and `return 1;`